# How to close a page.xaml in WinUI 3 by clicking the close button

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I have a program with **WinUI** 3 that Includes **MainWindow.xaml** and a **Page1.xaml**, I have a Button on the MainWindow, clicking on it Causes Page1 to Open and load Correctly, Now I have a **Close Button on Page1** That  I Want to be Able to Close Page1 by Clicking this Button. There Is no Method Like **This.Close** or **Unload** For the Page Object. Do You Have a Solution?  Please See the Picture

---

**Update:**
Note that Page1 is Loaded as a Pop-up by ContentDialog, But Actually Page1 is not Loaded in the Frame.

[image: pic]

Why is there really no simple solution? ( Microsoft )

Comment: So you want to close ContentDialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use an event for this. It should look something like this:

**Page1.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Page 1" />
        <Button
            Click="CloseButton_Click"
            Content="Close" />
    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;

namespace TestApp;

public sealed partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler? CloseRequested;

    private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseRequested?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

and your `ContentDialog`:

```cs
ContentDialog dialog = new();
dialog.XamlRoot = this.XamlRoot;

Page1 page = new();
page.CloseRequested += (s, e) => dialog.Hide();
dialog.Content = page;

ContentDialogResult result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a good solution and solved my code problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close ContentDialog, you can use Hide method:
`dialog.Hide();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added an update to the question and that page1 is opened as a popup and not in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the page's parent.

The following code uses @SimonMourier written [GetParent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73010064), the [Windowing](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/blob/046667c598540e887a303bd271a7524671363d65/Samples/Windowing/cs/cs-winui/WindowBasicsPage.xaml.cs#L19) sample and a button for an example.

```
private async void TitleBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TitleTextBox.Text.Contains("abc"))
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Content = "abc";
        btn.Click += (s,e) => 
        { 
            ContentDialog c = GetParent<ContentDialog>(s.As<Button>()); 
            c.Hide();
        };
        ContentDialog errorDialog = new ContentDialog()
        {
            Title = "Single line text only!",
            //Content = "Only a single line of text is supported for a window titlebar. Please modify your text accordingly.",
            Content = btn,
            CloseButtonText = "Ok"
        };
        errorDialog.XamlRoot = infoBar.XamlRoot;
        XamlRoot a = TitleTextBox.XamlRoot;
        ContentDialogResult result = await errorDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        _mainAppWindow.Title = TitleTextBox.Text;
    }
}
```